# Equivalent of OpenCv c++ api Vec2f,norm, acos in emgucv csharp

Tags: c#, c++, api, opencv, emgucv

Here are OpenCV api in c++.

```
Vec2f
norm
acos
```

Please suggest what will be c# equivalent api in emgucv?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It wasn't mine, but I understand the downvote. I was only able answer your question since I had seen you other, so understood the context. In the future, better to include the whole line of code with some context so that people can help you easier :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `Vec2f`

Depending on your application, you can just use `System.Drawing.PointF`, a float precision 2D point to store `I` and `J` as `X` and `Y`. However that won't support some of the opencv functions you may like to use. In which case, `Vec2f` is simply a 1 by 2 matrix of `float`, for this you can use:

```cs
Matrix<float> myVec2F = new Matrix<float>(1, 2);
```

As a bonus, use this class if you like:

```cs
public class Vec2F: Matrix<float>
{
    public float I
    {
        get { return base[0, 0]; }
        set { base[0, 0] = value; }
    }

    public float J
    {
        get { return base[1, 0]; }
        set { base[1, 0] = value; }
    }

    public Vec2F() : base(2, 1) { }

    public Vec2F(float I, float J) : base(2,1)
    {
        this.I = I;
        this.J = J;
    }
}
```

Used as:

```cs
Vec2F myVec2F = new Vec2F();
```

### `Norm`

In the context of 2D vectors, this is simply Pythagoras in order to find the magnitude, however if you've used the `Matrix<float>` above, it now supports `myVec2F.Norm`.

### `Acos`

`System.Math.Acos()`... simple.